# Papa Rudin - Prologue Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, exponential-function

My question concerns a step in the proof of the first theorem in Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis*.

From *Real and Complex Analysis* (p. 2-3):

> There exists a positive number $\pi$ such that $e^z = 1$ if
> and only if $\frac{z}{2\pi i}$ is an integer.

Now the relevant part of the proof:

> It follows that $e^{\pi i} = i^2 = -1$, $e^{2\pi i} = (-1)^2 = 1$, and then $e^{2\pi i n} = 1$ for
> every integer n. Also: \begin{equation} \tag{10} e^{z+2\pi i} = e^z \end{equation}If $z = x + iy$, $x$ and $y$ real, then $e^z$ = $e^xe^{iy}$; hence $\lvert e^z \rvert = e^x$. If $e^z = 1$, we therefore must have $e^x = 1$, so that $x = 0$.

Now I understand everything up to this point. The next step is where I don't understand:

> To prove that $\frac{y}{2\pi}$ must be an integer, it is enough to show that $e^y \neq 1$ if $0 < y < 2\pi$, by (10).

Why is this the case? If $\frac{y}{2\pi}$ is an integer then we have $e^{iy} = e^{2\pi i \frac{y}{2\pi}} = 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author makes a proof by contraposition.

First, since $e^{y+2\pi i} = e^y$, you can suppose that $y\in [0,2\pi]$.

You want to prove that if $e^iy=1$ then $\frac{y}{2\pi}$ is an integer.

So its the same as proving that if $\frac{y}{2\pi}$ is not an integer (i.e. $0<y<2\pi$ since $y\in [0,2\pi]$) then $e^i y \neq 1$.

Comment: That's incredibly obvious, and I'm slightly embarrassed that I didn't understand. I appreciate you spelling it out for me.